# didRequestRegionState fails on iOS 13

Tags: swift, core-location, core-bluetooth, ios13, ios-bluetooth

I have been working on an app the registers a region with core location for monitoring.

```
self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:proximtyId] identifier:@"com.hospitalintegration.region" ];
        if(self.beaconRegion){
            [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
            [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
        }
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Then the didStartMonitoringForRegion is called and i request region state in this method :

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    if(self.beaconRegion){
        [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
        [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    }
}
```

in iOS 12, this seems to work absolutely fine, didDetermineState is called and i get my desired result. but on iOS 13 didDetermineState is not called and always monitoringDidFailForRegion is called with the error.domain == kCLErrorDomain and error.code == 5.

APPLE'S DOCUMENTATION SAYS :

Monitoring can fail if the app has exceeded the maximum number of regions that it can monitor simultaneously. Monitoring can also fail if the region’s radius distance is too large.

Which i have checked is not a problem here. The region is small, as it is working on iOS 12, And i am only monitoring 1 region i have checked monitored regions count and it is 1. So, i dnt get what is wrong here.

Comment: Code 5 indicates a kCLErrorRegionMonitoringFailure. Apple has a documentation page describing that error, maybe that helps to resolve your issue: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/clerror/kclerrorregionmonitoringfailure

Comment: @Craz1k0ek please check i have updated the question.

Comment: How about the permissions, they have changed a lot since iOS 13. It appears region monitoring is only available when permissions are always given, take a look here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/choosing_the_location_services_authorization_to_request

Comment: issue is with bluetooth. on iOS 12 there was an alert asking to turn on bluetooth if it was turned off. on iOS 13 it is not appearing , once i initialized CBCentralManager now it is showing that alert to turn on Bluetooth from settings.